# Anime Js and opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, opacity

I wanted to use animate to translate and fade element but the opacity property doesn't affect the animation.
I've got so far :

```
let timeline1 = anime.timeline();

   timeline1.add({
      targets: '#operation .letter',
      translateY: [0,40],
      opacity: [0, 1],
      easing: "linear",
      duration: 300,
      delay: (el, i) =>   30 * i
    })
```

Translation and other properties work nicely but it seems that it doesn't change the opacity as a css property but as an attribute.

In the HTML, once rendered, the targets shows:

```
<span class="letter" opacity="1" style="transform: translateY(40px);">p</span>
```

It seems to get opacity as an attribute not like a css property

I tried to `opacity: 1, and opacity:"1"` both didn't change the animation

Thanks in advance,

Comment: it's on the first line `let timeline1 = anime.timeline();`

Comment: It is not necessary to include opacity in the tag. Because opacity=1 is already the default.

Comment: Could you show us the html. When using html inspector, when the animation is going on usually you should be able to see values in style attribute changes. Does it happens to opacity?

Answer (score 0):

I set the "opacity" property to 0 in the .css and configured the script like this:

```
var timeline = anime.timeline();

timeline.add({
    targets: '#home-intro',
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 4000,
}
);
```

Everything works fine, with and without timeline.